# Javascript for loop with attributes

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, for-loop

I have an ul tag with multiple li tags in with the same class.
in each li tag i want a different total of circles that is given with a data attribute named 'data-score', this is displayed in a div with the classes 'skill-progress' and 'js-progress'.
My problem is that all the circles are displayed in the first li tag.

**JS file**

```
const skill_score = function () {
  const totalli = document.getElementsByClassName('skills');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < totalli.length; i++) {
    const skill = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-progress');

    const score = skill[i].getAttribute('data-score');
    console.log(score);

    const displayElements = document.querySelector('.js-progress');
    console.log(displayElements);

    for (let i = 0; i < score; i++) {
      displayElements.innerHTML += `<i class="fas fa-circle active"></i>`;
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  console.info('DOM geladen'); skill_score();
});
```

**PHP content-skill file**

```
<li class="skills" id="skill">
  <span class="skill-title"><i class="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_skill_icon', true)?>"></i> <?</span>
  <div class="skill-progress js-progress" id="skill-progress" data-score="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, '_skill_score', true)?>">

  </div>
</li>
```

**Console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C9Hh.png)

**Home.php**

```
<?php

      $arg = array(
        'post_type'=> array( 'skill' ),
        'nopaging' => false,
        'posts_per_page' => '5',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'ID'
      );

      $query = new WP_Query($arg);

      if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('template-parts/post/content','skill');
        endwhile;
      endif;
      wp_reset_query(); 

    ?>
```

Comment: i updated the code above, i have 5 posts so that means 5 li tags but all the circles keep coming in the first li tag. but i can pick the score attribute from all the different li tags as you can see in the picture above

Comment: Both for loops use the same variable `i`. Consider changing the variable used in the inner loop in case that is causing the bug.